# Bluebird promises in Node.js

Tags: node.js

In the below code I need to call function1() and then function2().

Both functions do some asynchronous operations in it. So I wanted it to be called one after the other.

There is a mysql connection object that will be returned as a promise. So it has to be used in entire program finally closed at the end.

When I run the below code I don't get output it just stays blank and trying to debug it never hits function1.

**constants.js**

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = {
  getMySqlConnection: function () {
    var conObj = { host: "localhost", user: "root", password: "", database: "deccan" };

    var connection = require("mysql").createConnection(conObj);

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          connection.connect(function (error) { 
            if (error)
              reject(error);
            else
              resolve(connection);
          });
        });       
      }
    };
```

**testing.js**

```
var constants = require("./constants.js");
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var mysqlConnection = null;

constants.getMySqlConnection().then(function (connection) 
{
    mysqlConnection = connection;

    return new Promise(function1);

})
.catch(function (e) 
{
    console.log(e);

}).then(function (result) 
{
    console.log("Finished Everything");
});


function function1() 
{
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) 
    {
        var sql = "select *from employee";

        mysqlConnection.query(sql, function (error, results) 
        {
            if (error)
                reject(error);
            else
                resolve(results);
        });

    }).then(function (value) 
    {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) 
        {
            // do something here
        });

    });
}

function function2() 
{
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) 
    {
        var sql = "select *from management";

        mysqlConnection.query(sql, function (error, results) 
        {
            if (error)
                reject(error);
            else
                resolve(results);
        });    
    }).then(function (value) 
    {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) 
        {
            // do something here
        });        
    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe try changing "return new Promise(function1);" to "return function1();"

Comment: Make your life easier: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql